# Детские вопросы о рекламе

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление, словосочетания, реклама

• Реклама на канале ТНТ
*Радуйте близких **любого февраля** со скидками из ресторанов в Яндекс.Еде.*

•• Реклама на канале "Пятница"
*Радуйте близких **любого марта** со скидками на товары из магазинов на Яндекс.Еде.*

Девочка (11 лет) думает, что говорить *любого февраля, любого марта* неправильно (мне тоже так кажется, но вот почему — объяснения туманные).
И ещё *мы* предполагаем, что тут не всё в порядке с предлогами: *радуйте **со** скидками **из** ресторанов.*

Так **как** же надо написать грамотно? Или всё верно-верно?

Answer (score 2):

Есть родительный временной падеж: приехать первого сентября, получить посылку второго марта, получил хлебную карточку десятого мая.

Почему нельзя считать ***любого февраля*** родительный временным? Специфика сочетания, наверное, лишь в том, что в нëм, вопреки обыкновению, с существительным употреблено не порядковое числительные, а местоимение любой.

Приеду ***первого февраля*** — приеду ***любого февраля***.

Радуйте близких восьмого марта — радуйте близких ***любого марта***

К чему придраться? Разве что к нетипичности употребления в родительном временном местоимëнного слова.

Если пофилософствовать, то реклама — это в общем художественное произведение; к  рекламе текст пишется, и автор текста имеет право на свой авторский синтаксис, а понимаете ли вы его или нет — это ваши проблемы, проблемы зрителя и слушателя.

Что касается ***скидками из ресторанов***, то это абсолютно легитимное словосочетание, построенное по образцу словосочетаний типа *яблоки из Тбилиси*, *конфеты из магазина* со связью падежного примыкания и атрибутивным (определительным) значением зависимой формы с предлогом из.

Скидки из ресторанов = ресторанные скидки. Конечно, возможна и беспредложная конструкция ***скидка ресторана***. *Порадуйте близких скидками ресторанов*!

Для глагола ***радовать*** в литературном языке типично беспредложное управление творительным падежом (слабое управление). Р*адовать чем? Скидками*.

Возможно, привычнее звучало бы:

*Радуйте близких в любой день февраля скидками из ресторанов в Яндекс.Еде*

Вообще говоря, важен реальный смысл описываемой ситуации; каков он? Может быть, по смыслу это не непосредственно зритель радует близких скидками (зритель скидками не распоряжается), а зритель лишь сообщает близким о скидках, как-то направляет близких в ресторан, где можно со скидкой заказать еду, покушать; и вот для того-то авторы и употребили предложную конструкция *(то есть не радуйте скидками, а радуйте **со** скидками)*, чтобы немного ***отделить*** скидки от того, кто ими радует, — от зрителя.

Comment: Разовью вашу мысль о "со скидками". У меня две версии.
Оптимистичная — тоже связанная с контекстом: не близкие будут пользоваться скидками, а зритель закажет еду со скидкой и уже этой едой порадует близких.
Пессимистичная — это просто бездумная калька с английского.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, не нужно усложнять до временного родительного, кроме того фраза "радуйте скидками февраля" нормально согласована.
Нужно сделать начальную форму и посмотреть откуда это получилось:

Первого февраля - от первый (день) февраля, или от февральский первый день, или от (П)первое февраля. Любого февраля - любой (?) февраля, "февральский любой день" - тоже не звучит, хочется поставить предлог - "в любой февральский день", "февральский - любой" - может быть в качестве ответа на какой-то вопрос, но тире уже указывает на информативный разрыв, "любой" и "февральский" вообще никак не связаны между собой, это два разных прилагательных, в то время как числительное сразу понятно к чему февральскому относится...

То есть, если в первом случае "первый" = "первый день", так как это уже сложившееся употребление, идиоматика, то во втором случае не ясно любой "что?" или "кто?". То есть если первая фраза типична, то вторая фраза нетипична, то есть это сленг, она в целом понятна, но так не говорят, либо тут какой-то подвох, прикол.

И второй момент, "любого февраля" или "любого марта" тяготеет к "любому месяцу", то есть тут происходит так же конфликт с другим возможным значением фразы, когда речь идет не о днях в месяце, а разных месяцах в году. Например: снег любого февраля обильно лежит повсюду.

То есть мы имеем: нетипичное употребление, конфликтующее с возможным другим значением подобной связки.

И третий момент, предлог "со", радуйте со(!?) скидками...

Радуйте близких каждый день, любого марта месяца, скидки на товары из магазинов(из магазинов тоже лишнее) на Яндекс.Еде.

Comment: Любого февраля — это, конечно, прикол. Реклама же! Надо, чтобы вы обратили внимание, обсуждали и т.д. Вот мы и обсуждаем))  Товары из магазинов на Яндекс.Еде? Может, там еще тарелки можно купить?

Comment: Это какие-то юр моменты, типа Яндекс это не магазин, а площадка-витрина для магазинов и доставка, если пришлют невкусное виноват не Яндекс, а магазин. Но зачем этот юр нарратив вплетать в рекламный слоган я не знаю. Короче понамешано по стилистике всего понемногу, постмодерн.

Comment: Как это зачем? Чтобы вы пользовались их доставкой.  Эта Яндекс. Еда всюду. Вот иду сейчас по улице, навстречу мне трое ребят, еще секунд 10, и между нами прохода не будет. И вот Яндекс,Еда с ювелирной точностью на высокой скорости проскакивает между нами. Вот такие там специалисты! Правда, одного паренька он, видно, слегка задел, тот так задумчиво на него обернулся.

Comment: Зачем смешивать юр стилистику не понятно, получается слишком наворочено и непросто. А так да, курьеры они такие.

Comment: Спасибо, Буратино, за внимание к вопросу.  А скидки **из** ресторанов — это правильно? Так **как** все-таки нужно написать? (Ваше последнее предложение мне совсем не понятно.)

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова скидки из ресторанов — это правильно? - более-менее, разговорно сойдет. Писать правильно, смотря для чего правильно, для рекламы вот как написано - правильно, потому что цель рекламы, чтобы привлекала внимание и заедала в голове, заедает же? значит, для рекламного стиля правильно. Хотя некоторые моменты мне не понятны, зачем со скидками и упоминание юр моментов про магазины, но вероятно, у тех кто составлял подобный слоган были веские причины так выражаться. И реклама будет генерировать неправильные словоформы, сленг и тп, не потому что это правильно, а как раз наоборот.

Comment: Это рекламный метод и стиль неправильного построения фраз соответствует. Если исправить все фразы, это будет уже совсем не реклама, а что-то выхолощенное. Ну то есть это какой-то снобизм и ханжество, прийти к морякам и заставить их выражаться литературно. Это тоже русский, новый русский, вот такой какой есть. Его можно попробовать интегрировать, а бороться с этим бесполезно

Comment: Ну хорошо... Только как это разъяснить ребенку, который обратил внимание на все "неправильности"? P. S. Но Ваше последнее предложение в ответе я все равно не понимаю. *Радуйте близких каждый день, любого марта месяца, скидки на товары из магазинов(из магазинов тоже лишнее) на Яндекс.Еде.*

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова я попробовал исправить, но как видите, сильно лучше не стало, хотя, наверное, у меня творческого таланта не хватило.) Вывод, что исправлять нужно не всё, что не правильно, потому что есть неправильное, которое не исправимо, и оно имеет место быть. Наверное, знание различной стилистики, и умение её своевременно применять важнее, чем стараться всё унифицировать под один стиль и одну форму, пусть даже "правильную" и литературную. Есть случаи, когда литературный стиль неуместен, либо он не достаточно совершенен, но это другой момент, это нужно быть мастером слова, писателем, поэтом